# I want to fetch autoincremented varchar values from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I want to fetch autoincremented `varchar` values from SQL Server 2008 into a textbox in asp.net in `pageload` event.

Suppose I have a column `trn_no`, data type `varchar`. If the 1st value inserted manually in the table, like `T100`, then how would I get the value `T101` in the textbox in pageload.

please help me.

Comment: Do all of the rows have a `T` prefix? Don't store the prefix and just use a numeric `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: What do you have? Show us what you've tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have alphanumeric values in key then use following sql to get last inserted id +1.

```
SELECT 'T' 
       + Cast(Max(Substring(trn_no, 2, Len(trn_no)-1) + 1 ) AS varchar(15)) 
FROM   table
```

Change `Varchar(15)` as per possible max length

Comment: And what happens when two concurrent transactions try and insert?

Comment: Op wants to display incremented id, he is not asking about concurrency issue.